# \i '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/tables/users.sql' in .sql file shows errors. Can't figure out why

Tags: postgresql, docker

This is my code that i was following along. My docker is well setup but for some reason the deploy_schema.sql is showing errors. I know sql commands but it shouldn't show errors like this.

What is the issue here??
[The image of my code in vs-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE5v2.png)

Comment: Is the ERROR hidden someplace in that image?

Comment: @jjanes Hi there !! yes . I hovered over the lines and it only shows this:

Incorrect syntax near ''/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/tables/users.sql''.

Comment: it also shows 'i' is not a recognized option.
and 
Incorrect syntax near '\'.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Thanks brother. Didn't know it. Will not do it from the next time!